# Reactive Spring Cloud Stream with RabbitMQ binder: Manual ACK

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

So I have a reactive `Consumer` and RabbitMQ as a Binder implementation, it basically looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void accept(Flux<Message<Event>> eventMessages) {
        eventMessages
                .buffer(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .flatMap(messages -> ... )
                .buffer(Duration.of(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .flatMap(messages -> ...)
                .doOnNext(this::acknowledgeMessage)
                .subscribe();
    }


    private void acknowledgeMessage(Message<Event> message) {
        var channel = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL, Channel.class);
        var deliveryTag = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG, Long.class);

        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);

        log.info("Message acknowledged");
    }
```

The thing is that I only need to acknowledge a message when all of the operations finish successfully but I'm pretty sure `channel.basicAck` call is blocking.
Is there a reactive alternative to this? And just in case -- how will that blocking call affect the overall performance and stuff? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`basicAck` can block (but usually doesn't, as long as you are using different connections for publishers and consumers, which is recommended).

You could use a `.publishOn()` before the `doOnNext()` to hand it off to another thread.

Comment: `Mono.<Void>fromRunnable(() -> channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false))
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnNext(nothing -> log.info("Message acknowledged"))`
Should that work?

Comment: One more, If I may -- how to ensure that publishers and consumers do use different connections?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, that should do it. See `RabbitTemplate.setUsePublisherConnection(true)`.